# How to find unique values in array

Tags: php, html, php-5.2

Here i want to find  `unique` values,so i am writing code like this but i can't get answer,for me don't want to array format.i want only string

```
<?php
$array = array("kani","yuvi","raja","kani","mahi","yuvi") ;
$unique_array = array(); // unique array
$duplicate_array = array(); // duplicate array
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
  if(!in_array($value,$unique_array)){
       $unique_array[$key] = $value;
  }else{
     $duplicate_array[$key] = $value;
  }
  }
  echo "unique values are:-<br/>";
  echo "<pre/>";print_r($unique_array);

  echo "duplicate values are:-<br/>";
  echo "<pre/>";print_r($duplicate_array);

?>
```

Comment: *i want only string* - show output you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You can use `array_unique()` in single line like below:-*

```
<?php

$unique_array = array_unique($array); // get unique value from initial array

echo "<pre/>";print_r($unique_array); // print unique values array
?>
```

*Output:- https://eval.in/601260*

*Reference:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php*

***If you want in string format:-***

```
echo implode(',',$final_array);
```

*Output:-https://eval.in/601261*

The way you want is here:-

https://eval.in/601263

OR

https://eval.in/601279

Answer (score 2):

I am baffled by your selection as the accepted answer -- I can't imagine how it can possibly satisfy your requirements.

`array_count_values()` has been available since PHP4, so that is the hero to call upon here.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/amTMl))

```
$array = array("kani","yuvi","raja","kani","mahi","yuvi") ;

$counts = array_count_values($array);  // since php4
foreach ($counts as $value => $count) {
    if ($count == 1) {
        $uniques[] = $value;
    } else {
        $duplicates[] = $value;
    }
}

echo "unique values: " , implode(", ", $uniques) , "\n";
echo "duplicate values: " , implode(", ", $duplicates);
```

Output:

```
unique values: raja, mahi
duplicate values: kani, yuvi
```

Answer (score 1):

To get unique values from array use `array_unique()`:

```
$array = array(1,2,1,5,10,5,10,7,9,1) ;
array_unique($array);
print_r(array_unique($array));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 10
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 9
)
```

And to get duplicated values in array use `array_count_values()`:

```
$array = array(1,2,1,5,10,5,10,7,9,1) ;
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 3 // 1 is duplicated value as it occurrence is 3 times
    [2] => 1
    [5] => 2 // 5 is duplicated value as it occurrence is 3 times
    [10] => 2 // 10 is duplicated value as it occurrence is 3 times
    [7] => 1
    [9] => 1
)
```

Comment: I need which are the values is unique value and which are the value for duplicate how we can find

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $arr1 = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,1,3,5,3,20];    
  print_r(arr_unique($arr1)); // will print unique values
  echo "<br>";
  arr_count_val($arr1); // will print array with duplicate values

  function arr_unique($arr) {
    sort($arr);
    $curr = $arr[0];
    $uni_arr[] = $arr[0];
    for($i=0; $i<count($arr);$i++){
       if($curr != $arr[$i]) {
         $uni_arr[] = $arr[$i];
         $curr = $arr[$i];
       }
    }
    return $uni_arr;
  }

  function arr_count_val($arr) {
    $uni_array = arr_unique($arr1);
    $count = 0;

    foreach($uni_array as $n1) {
      foreach($arr as $n1) {
        if($n1 == $n2) {
          $count++;
        }
      }
    echo "$n1"." => "."$count"."<br>";
    $count=0;
    }
  }
?>
```